# Right slide secondary menu in android

Tags: android, slider, actionbarsherlock

I got sliding menu lib from [here](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/), i dont no what is wrong here, in this right side slide menu appears but its blank. here is the code

```
// customize the SlidingMenu
        SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
        sm.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
        sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        //sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);



        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Here is the way i'm calling secondarymenu

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            showSecondaryMenu();

            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is the way i'm instantiating the fragment.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_frame);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.home_screen, new MapFragment())
        .commit();

        getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.activity_home_frame);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.home_screen, new MapFragment())
        .commit();

        // set the Behind View
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_settings_frame);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.settings_screen, new SettingsFragment())
        .commit();
```

my map fragment

```
public class MapFragment extends SherlockFragment{

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_map, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }

}
```

settings fragment

```
public class SettingsFragment extends SherlockFragment{

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_settings, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }

}
```

settings layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Settings view."
        ></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

map layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your map "
        ></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

kindly tell why i'm getting right side menu blank?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It got worked, problem is. instead of this

```
 getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.activity_home_frame);
```

i need to call

```
getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryMenu(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_map, null));
```